# How do I replace all strings in only one column with a certain integer?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a Pandas DataFrame with one column called “death”. It contains zeros, ones and also dates. The date values are all strings, and I wish to replace all strings (just in this column) with the integer 1. Without replacing the zero values.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, the linked answer doesn’t answer my question... I don’t want to replace ALL values in the column

Comment: So while your edit makes this no longer a duplicate, I'd recommend providing code you've already tried that isn't working to promote this as a candidate for re-opening. While it's no longer a duplicate, we still need to see your code that isn't working to effectively help.

Comment: Try this `df.loc[df['death'].isin([0,1])==False , 'death'] = 1` or if the data is of type string then `df.loc[df['death'].isin(['0','1'])==False , 'death'] = 1`